# Extract certain section from string

Tags: php, regex, string

I have a string that contains a section of text I wish to extract in a variable. In the string below I would like to extract anything with a `/` in it.

```
$str = 'this is a random string foo/bar random - string words';
```

In the above example I would like to extract `foo/bar`. Currently I do this by `exploding` the string at the spaces and then looping through and checking if each section contains a `/`.

```
$words = explode(' ', $str);
foreach($words as $word) {
    if(strpos($word, '/') !== false) {
        $myVar = $word;
    }
}
```

Is there a beeter way of doing this as I need to do this for a lot of text strings?

Comment: What you're doing isn't that bad. You could turn it around, first explode on `/`, and then find the spaces on either side. That would be slightly more efficient. It would be more efficient if you avoided using an array altogether.

Comment: steve  is your string contain multiple time `/` or only single time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know exactly that you need to match two words composed of lowercase letters separated with `/`, then a multi-match regex would also be fine, something like this

```
preg_match_all('%[a-z]+/[a-z]+%', $subject, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($result[0]); $i++) {
    # Matched text = $result[0][$i];
}
```

Output:- https://eval.in/596292

The efficiency, however, should be tested experimentally

Comment: Thanks - how would i modify this so it matches numbers to? e,g `my string foo123/bar321 my string`

Comment: @steve If you have characters then numbers, then `[a-z]+\d+/[a-z]+\d+`, if they can mix, then `[a-z0-9]+/[a-z0-9]+`

Comment: Thanks - i just tried `%[a-z]+\d+/[a-z]+\d+%` and the function failed to find a result.

Comment: @steve strange, could you provide an example of the text and the code? I just ran it, and everything worked

Comment: No it doesn't. Try `11one/11one` or `one1two2/four4five5`. Your regex does not catch [number][letter] nor number inside letters. Your pattern only matches with letters first then numbers.

Comment: @Andreas [a-z0-9]+/[a-z0-9]+, you need the second regex for mixed numbers and letters

Answer (score 0):

I would use: `preg_match_all("/(\w+\/\w+)[\s|$]/", $str, $output);`

Now $output[1] is an array with the matches.
The pattern matches a word followed by slash then a word again, then it needs a space or end of string. That means it will not match strings like:
`last/string/to/test`

https://3v4l.org/r8p2g

Comment: Thanks - this doesn't pick up a match if there is a number in the word?

Comment: Yes it does. Wait a sec.

Comment: Mine matches capital letters too, which buld0zzers does not

Answer (score 0):

Well, the best solution would be a regex, as stated by the others. But you have to be clear what you want to match, e.g. **'anything with a / in it'** would match your whole sentence. I guess in your case it would be easiest to say everything BUT white spaces:

```
<?php
$str = 'this is a random string foo/bar random - string words - another/example';
preg_match_all('#[^ ]+\/[^ ]+#', $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

> array(1) {   [0]=>   array(2) {
>       [0]=>
>       string(7) "foo/bar"
>       [1](https://glot.io/snippets/eg0llgtir4)=>
>       string(15) "another/example"   } }

[see here for a running example](https://glot.io/snippets/eg0llgtir4)

Of course this is to some degree a matter of personal taste, if i want to catch something in a greedy way i prefer to extract by exclusion.